# Reading this XML structure in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order>
<order_businessid>2</order_businessid>
<order_categoryid>3</order_categoryid>

<product_id>1</product_id>
<product_name1>CreamCheese Cake</product_name1>
<product_price1>4.10</product_price1>
<product_Qty1>1</product_Qty1>

<product_id>3</product_id>
<product_name2>Gujarati unlimited</product_name2>
<product_price2>50.00</product_price2>
<product_Qty2>1</product_Qty2>

<product_id>5</product_id>
<product_name3>Cheese French Frish</product_name3>
<product_price3>4.10</product_price3>
<product_Qty3>1</product_Qty3>
</order>
```

How can i read this structure?

I would like to output in PHP:

```
ProduktID 1, has name CreamCheese Cake and it's price is 4.10
ProduktID 3, has name Gujarati unlimited and it's price is 50.00
```

and so on..

I know how to do this if all info was inside one element, then i would just loop through the elements, get attributes and output.

But with this i dont know at all, so hope you can help me out..

Comment: That's some pretty lousy XML.  Use the same names, and group elements together.  Don't for example, product_name3?  Just use name, and group all product data as elements / attributes under a single product element.

Comment: XML like this comes from developers that create XML with strings, not DOM methods.  Just cause it has <> tags in it doesn't make it XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the XML is very poor - having each product on the order with in a correct structure would make this a lot easier.

But this works (using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)):

```
$myxml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order>
<order_businessid>2</order_businessid>
<order_categoryid>3</order_categoryid>

<product_id>1</product_id>
<product_name1>CreamCheese Cake</product_name1>
<product_price1>4.10</product_price1>
<product_Qty1>1</product_Qty1>

<product_id>3</product_id>
<product_name2>Gujarati unlimited</product_name2>
<product_price2>50.00</product_price2>
<product_Qty2>1</product_Qty2>

<product_id>5</product_id>
<product_name3>Cheese French Frish</product_name3>
<product_price3>4.10</product_price3>
<product_Qty3>1</product_Qty3>
</order>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($myxml);
$count=1;
foreach ($xml->product_id as $prod) { 
 $pn = $xml->xpath('/order/product_name'.$count);
 $price = $xml->xpath('/order/product_price'.$count);
 $pq = $xml->xpath('/order/product_Qty'.$count);

 echo "ProduktID $prod, has name $pn[0] and it's price is $price[0] and exists $pq[0] time(s)".PHP_EOL;
 $count++;
}
```

Working example : http://codepad.org/R00NJhOr

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your problem , but i wont prefer this XML format

```
$xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order>
<order_businessid>2</order_businessid>
<order_categoryid>3</order_categoryid>

<product_id>1</product_id>
<product_name1>CreamCheese Cake</product_name1>
<product_price1>4.10</product_price1>
<product_Qty1>1</product_Qty1>

<product_id>3</product_id>
<product_name2>Gujarati unlimited</product_name2>
<product_price2>50.00</product_price2>
<product_Qty2>1</product_Qty2>

<product_id>5</product_id>
<product_name3>Cheese French Frish</product_name3>
<product_price3>4.10</product_price3>
<product_Qty3>1</product_Qty3>
</order>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

$pid = $pnam = $ppric = '';
foreach($xml as $ky=>$node)  {
    $pid = ( $ky == 'product_id') ? $node[0] : $pid ;
    $pnam = (strpos($ky, 'product_name') === 0) ? $node[0] : $pnam;
    $ppric = (strpos($ky, 'product_price') === 0) ? $node[0] : $ppric;

    if( strpos($ky, 'product_price') === 0)  {
        echo "product id $pid has name $pnam and its price is $ppric <br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehm... honestly? There exists developer who call this a xml structure? xD

There are several ways to handle such crap. I prefer regular expressions:

This one should fit your requirements:

```
/.*?<product_id>(.*?)<\/product_id>.*?<product_name\d*>(.*?)<\/product_name\d*>.*?<product_price\d*>(.*?)<\/product_price\d*>.*?<product_Qty\d*>(.*?)<\/product_Qty\d*>.*/s
```

and

```
ProduktID $1, has name $2 and it's price is $3 and exists $4 time(s).\n
```

This should work with a preg_match_all, but it is untested!

Best regards!

Comment: Im agreeing with you, but I cant do anything about it. The XML structure has been made from a app developer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->load("order.xml");

$productList = array();

foreach($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    if($node->tagName == "product_id") {
        $productList[] = array(
            "id" => $node->textContent,
        );
    }

    if(preg_match("/product_([A-Za-z_]+)(\d+)/", $node->tagName, $m)) {
        $productList[$m[2] - 1][$m[1]] = $node->textContent;
    }
}

foreach($productList as $product) {
    echo "ProduktID ", $product["id"]
        , ", has name ", $product["name"]
        , " and it's price is ", $product["price"]
        , " with quantity ", $product["Qty"]
        , "\n";
}
```

Of course, that XML looks really strange (so I share @Armin's sentiment). It looks like it's "hand made" without one of those fancy XML tools/libraries but rather with string concatenation or just rendering with `echo`.